# ActionController::UnknownFormat respond_with using Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm trying to fetch data in my collection but I'm getting a UnknownFormat error in Rails. I'm following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1) RailsCast to get myself to learn a bit of Backbone.

I'm at the part where we are rendering data in a view through a collection, but when I use the example code I get a UnknownFormat error.

This is my Rails MoviesController

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Movie.all
    if logged_in?
      @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
      @movies = @user.movies
    end
  end
```

This is my Rails Router file,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'sessions/new'

  root               'movies#index'
  get   'signup'  => 'users#new'

  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

  scope "api" do
    resources :movies, :defaults => {:format => "json"}
  end

  resources :users
```

And this is my Backbone collection

```
class Movieseat.Collections.Movieseats extends Backbone.Collection

    url: '/api/movies'
```

I've did some research and found that a lot of people say I needed to add `, :defaults => {:format => "json"}` to my movie resource. But this hasn't helped me. Does anyone know what's causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem just today. I have two possible fixes for this...

1) Simply remove the respond_to, respond_with syntax and replace it with the `render json` syntax:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all

    if logged_in?
      @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
      @movies = @user.movies
    end
    render json: @movies.to_json
  end
end
```

I understand that this may not be ideal, but this is what worked for me.

2) This one I have not attempted, but it may be worth a try (not to be used with the first solution).

Somewhere in your backbone setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({       
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: If I use `respond_to :json, :html` instead of just `respond_to :json` I don't get the UnknownFormat error but it does give me a error when I use `- @movies.each do |movie|
    %div{:class => "movie-frame"} 
      = movie.title` saying `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I suppose I am not understanding how you plan to use backbone in this case. I thought you were supplying @movies as json to a backbone collection. Is this not the case? Also, I suppose the obvious thing to do here is to make sure that your movies model is actually pulling back data. Try opening up a rails console and doing a `Movie.all`

Comment: Ah that might be it. Well I'm learning Backbone and I'm mixing some stuff up. Mixing Backbone and Rails stuff.

Comment: When I use `render json: @movies.to_json` I get the json output on my index. It's probably because I'm rendering json in the index, how did you fix this?

Comment: If you're just starting backbone this may be a bit confusing, but basically you're going to want to set your backbone collection up to point to the movies API you have created on your Rails server. Then you will be able to manipulate the collection in your view javascript file and render it to a backbone template. Follow?